# Unable to parse input date containing abbreviated asian components using DateTimeFormatter

Tags: java, datetime, parsing, localdate, chinese-locale

I'm trying to parse a date string to LocalDate or LocalDateTime (actually any Temporal object), which contains asian abbreviated parts. When I provide a valid abbreviated chinese component(in example below - dayOfMonth), I get DateTimeParseException. Note that for the same scenario for other languages, this works just fine.

Examples:

`LocalDate.parse("2022年2月12日 週六", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("y年M月d日 EE", Locale.TRADITIONAL_CHINESE))` returns error **Text '2022年2月12日 週六' could not be parsed at index 10**.

However, if we use the non-abbreviated version (2022年2月12日 星期六), everything works fine.

If we take similar input in Spanish for example:
`LocalDate.parse("sáb. 12 feb. 2022", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EE. dd MMM. y", Locale.forLanguageTag("es-ES")))`, it will parse as expected.

Notes:
I'm taking the abbreviated components from the standard [CLDR data](https://github.com/unicode-cldr/cldr-dates-full/blob/204e99e8b28a52239bb6de1bbc89986cb19c0d50/main/zh-Hant/ca-gregorian.json#L113).

Is it at all possible to parse this input using any standard library?

Comment: I cannot reproduce on Java 17. It parses the string successfully. What version of Java are you using? Maybe they are not using that version of the CLDR?

Comment: Hello, I was using Java 8. Changed to 17 and it worked for me. Turns out they updated the CLDR data used in java.time.LocalDate. Should've tried it sooner.
Thanks!